# Probability of rolling a six on seven die?

Tags: probability

How would one calculate the probability of rolling a six (at least once) on seven dice? Would I be correct in proposing $1 - P(\text{no sixes})$ which is $1 - (5/6) ^ 7$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, since "no sixes" is the complementary event to "at least one 6".

$$P(\text{at least one 6}) = 1 - P(\text{no 6 at all}) = 1 - (5/6)^7$$

If the question was "exactly one six" it would be different, but that does not seem to be the question.